# F# or Ocaml optimization

Tags: python, f#, ocaml

I am trying to understand why the following Python code run faster than the F# and Ocaml versions:

```
from sys import stdin, stdout

def read():
    return stdin.readline().rstrip()
    
def readints():
    return [int(x) for x in read().split()]

_, _, q = readints()
A = readints()
B = readints()

for _ in range(q):
    arr = [0]*4001
    l1, r1, l2, r2 = readints()
    for i in range(l1-1, r1):
        arr[A[i]] ^= 1
    for i in range(l2-1, r2):
        arr[B[i]] ^= 1
    result = sum(arr)
    stdout.write(str(result)+"\n")
```

Here is the Ocaml version I came up with a couple of hours learning about the language:

```
let open Printf in
let parse_line () =
    read_line()
    |> String.trim
    |> Str.split (Str.regexp_string " ")
    |> Array.of_list
    |> Array.map int_of_string in
let nmq = parse_line() in
let n = nmq.(0) in
let m = nmq.(1) in
let q = nmq.(2) in
let a = parse_line() in
let b = parse_line() in
for i = 1 to q do
    let arr = Array.create 4001 0 in
    let llrr = parse_line() in
    let l1 = llrr.(0) in
    let r1 = llrr.(1) in
    let l2 = llrr.(2) in
    let r2 = llrr.(3) in
    for i = l1-1 to r1-1 do
        arr.(a.(i)) <- arr.(a.(i)) lxor 1
    done;
    for i = l2-1 to r2-1 do
        arr.(b.(i)) <- arr.(b.(i)) lxor 1
    done;
    printf "%d\n" (Array.fold_left (+) 0 arr)
done;
```

This is the same but in F#

```
open System
open System.IO
let out = new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput())
let readints () = [ for x in stdin.ReadLine().TrimEnd().Split() -> int(x) ]
let mutable [ _; _; q ] = readints()
let a = readints()
let b = readints()
for _ in 1..q do
  let arr = Array.create 4001 0
  let [ l1; r1; l2; r2 ] = readints()
  for i in l1-1 .. r1-1 do
    arr.[a.[i]] <- arr.[a.[i]] ^^^ 1
  for i in l2-1 .. r2-1 do
    arr.[b.[i]] <- arr.[b.[i]] ^^^ 1
  out.WriteLine(Array.sum(arr))
out.Close()
```

Example input:

```
5 5 2     
76 56 34 52 12
10 91 86 10 91    
1 5 2 5
2 2 2 5
```

Output:

```
7
3
```

Any ideas about how could I improve the performance of the Ocaml or F# programs? Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Implementing @FyodorSoikin and @JL0PD the F# code now passes 2 out of the 5 test cases:

```
open System
open System.IO

let out = new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput())

let readints () = [| for x in stdin.ReadLine().TrimEnd().Split() -> int(x) |]

let mutable q = readints().[2]
let a = readints()
let b = readints()

for t=1 to q do
  let arr = Array.zeroCreate 4001
  let llrr = readints()
  let l1 = llrr.[0]
  let r1 = llrr.[1]
  let l2 = llrr.[2]
  let r2 = llrr.[3]
  for i = l1-1 to r1-1 do
    arr.[a.[i]] <- arr.[a.[i]] ^^^ 1
  for i = l2-1 to r2-1 do
    arr.[b.[i]] <- arr.[b.[i]] ^^^ 1
  out.WriteLine(Array.sum(arr))

out.Close()
```

Comment: How do you know that the Python code is faster?

Comment: One potential slowdown I can see is random-accessing lists `a.[i]` and `b.[i]`. In your example input these are short, so it shouldn't matter that much, but I guess it can add up in a large loop.

Comment: Have you tried to compile your code? ;) Mostly likely you just run your code without compiling, e.g., `ocaml example.ml`, while what you need is `ocamlopt example.ml -o example` and then run `./example`. This is a guess, of course, so please, provide the full details of your experiment, e.g., how you build your code, how you measure the time and so on.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin in the Ocaml version I am actually using arrays with the `a.(i)`, where you see `a.[i]` is actually the F# syntax for arrays as opposed to list access. I know Python is faster because this solution passes all the tests:  https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/29856065

Comment: @ivg The environment codechef.com is using already `ocamlopt`, thanks for the answers!

Comment: In addition to @FyodorSoikin, iterating with `for i=l2-1 to r2-1 do` should be faster than `for i in l2-1 .. r2-1` because it won't create any enumerable. Also use `Array.zeroCreate` to create array of default values, that's a bit faster. But I think that heaviest slowdown because of usage lists instead of array or `ResizeArray` which is closer to python's `list`.
To note: answer is run on pypy instead of pure cpython, which gives JIT and significant performance improvement

Comment: Thanks for explaining that @JL0PD, didn't realise I was using a list comprehension instead of an array comprehension, I updated the question with the new code and it is in fact much faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more idiomatic OCaml code, though you didn't tell what was the task, so the implementation just follows yours as close as possible

```
open Printf

let parse_line () =
  read_line () |> String.trim |>
  String.split_on_char ' ' |>
  List.map int_of_string |>
  Array.of_list


let main () =
  match parse_line () with
  | [|n;m;q|] ->
    let a = parse_line () in
    let b = parse_line () in
    let arr = Array.make 4001 0 in
    for i = 1 to q do
      match parse_line () with
      | [|l1; r1; l2; r2 |] ->
        Array.fill arr 0 (Array.length arr) 0;
        for i = l1-1 to r1-1 do
          arr.(a.(i)) <- arr.(a.(i)) lxor 1
        done;
        for i = l2-1 to r2-1 do
          arr.(b.(i)) <- arr.(b.(i)) lxor 1
        done;
        printf "%d\n" (Array.fold_left (+) 0 arr)
      | _ -> failwith "wrong input: expects four numbers"
    done
  | _ -> failwith "wrong input on line 1: expects three numbers"

let () = main ()
```

It uses a bit more efficient `parse_line` function that doesn't rely on regular expressions for string splitting, though I don't think it really matters given that it is not called that often (assuming that `q` is small). Another small optimization is that I moved array creation out of the loop and just refill it with zeros instead of creating a new one on each iteration (also a minor optimization, which I do not expect to have a big effect, given how fast OCaml'
s GC is working).

A better implementation would eschew the intermediate `arr` value at all.

Also, I don't really think that the Python implementation is faster than OCaml or F# in absolute numbers, I think it is not passing the test because it is slower than other OCaml implementations.

P.S. after finding the actual [task](https://www.codechef.com/problems/ODTPIC) I can see that `q` could be quite large and `parse_line` will become the bottleneck and there is a lot of room for improvement here.

Additionally, the weakest point of your approach is that you're doing 4k iterations and creating an array of 4k entries, both are totally unnecessary and performance-critical. You just need to count the number of topic, so allocating an array of 4k entries for each possible topic number is not optimal. You can use hashtables for that.

Comment: That is a great answer, thanks for that. I like your Ocaml version, it is not only faster but also more elegant. You are right in saying the Python implementation is not faster than OCaml or F# , I actually resubmitted the Python solution that was passing the 5 tests cases last years and now it is not the case. It only passes now 2 out of the 5, just like F# and Ocaml. It seems like Codechef itself changed the specs.

Answer (score 1):

Here is finally a version that passes 5 of the 5 test cases in F#. I don't believe this problem can be solved today in Python as the current constraints in the platform.

```
open System
open System.Collections

// Required manually implementation since the old .NET didn't support BitOperations.PopCount
let cardinality (bitArray: BitArray) =
    let arr: int32[] = Array.create ((bitArray.Length >>> 5) + 1) 0
    bitArray.CopyTo(arr, 0)
    let mutable count = 0
    let n = arr.Length-1
    arr.[n] <- arr.[n] &&& (~~~(-1 <<< (bitArray.Count % 32)))
    for i = 0 to n do
        let mutable c = arr.[i]
        c <- c - ((c >>> 1) &&& 0x55555555)
        c <- (c &&& 0x33333333) + ((c >>> 2) &&& 0x33333333)
        c <- ((c + (c >>> 4) &&& 0xF0F0F0F) * 0x1010101) >>> 24
        count <- count + c
    count

let readints () = [| for x in stdin.ReadLine().TrimEnd().Split() -> int(x) |]

let [| n; m; q |] = readints()
let a = readints()
let b = readints()

let abits = Array.init (n+5) (fun _ -> BitArray(4005))
let bbits = Array.init (m+5) (fun _ -> BitArray(4005))

for i = 1 to n do
    let k = a.[i-1]
    abits.[i] <- BitArray(abits.[i-1])
    abits.[i].[k] <- not abits.[i].[k]

for i = 1 to m do
    let k = b.[i-1]
    bbits.[i] <- BitArray(bbits.[i-1])
    bbits.[i].[k] <- not bbits.[i].[k]

for i = 1 to q do
  let [| l1; r1; l2; r2 |] = readints()
  let result = BitArray(abits.[l1-1]).Xor(BitArray(abits.[r1]))
  result.Xor(BitArray(bbits.[l2-1]).Xor(BitArray(bbits.[r2])))
  printfn "%d" (cardinality result)
```